# Custom CMS features in ASP.NET MVC site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, content-management-system

We have a requirement for our partners to built a CMS in which some of pages on the site should be configurable by them using the admin panel. So we are planning to create a static website with pre-defined layout and pages and replace those content when partner users will make changes in admin panel.

Now the problem is that this application will be used by multiple partners and if one will edit the information through admin panel then it should not effect the other partners custom pages.

The solution which we are thinking is to replicate the same code on multiple domains for each set of partners and replace the content. Can somebody suggest how can we do in one domain and not replicating the code again and again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We resolved it by creating the sub-domains for each partner and by creating a standard HTML page with fixed layout and saving the customizable information in database for each partner like text, image paths etc. Then depending upon the partner we get the dynamic content from database and replace on page using jquery.  So no need to duplicate the code and no manual effort.